# How to get ID for dynamically created views

Tags: android, contextmenu, dynamic-programming

I'm working on a demo. In that I'm Dynamically created the `ImageView` and multiple  `TextView`. I set the `contextMenu` on them. Everyting is working fine. What I want is, when I go for `contextMenu` how can I get the Id of selected `View` to perform further operation..

Following is my code...

```
   public class ModifyCard extends Fragment implements OnClickListener, OnTouchListener{

    private AlertDialog dialog;
    //Declaration of framelayout
    FrameLayout f;
    //Declaration of imageview
    ImageView imageview;
    View view;
    File file;
    EditText et1;
     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_modify_card ,container, false);
        captureImageInitialization();
        Initialize();
        return view;
       }
     private void Initialize() {
            f=(FrameLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.framelayout);
            Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
            int myInt;
            myInt = bundle.getInt("position");
            ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getActivity());
            f.setBackgroundResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[myInt]);

            LinearLayout layout=new LinearLayout(getActivity());
            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            imageview=new ImageView(getActivity());
            EditText EditTextUserName=new EditText(getActivity());
            EditText EditTextUsesrMobNumber=new EditText(getActivity());
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams ivparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(150,150);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams EditTextUserNameParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                                     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                                                     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams EditTextUsesrMobNumberParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                                     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                                                     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            ivparams.setMargins(0,10,10,0);         
            imageview.setId(1);
           imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_user_default);
           imageview.setLayoutParams(ivparams);

            EditTextUserNameParams.setMargins(10,-5,0,0);
            EditTextUserName.setId(3);
            EditTextUserName.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            EditTextUserName.getBackground().setAlpha(0);
            EditTextUserName.setHint("Enter Your Name");
            EditTextUserName.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            EditTextUserName.setLayoutParams(EditTextUserNameParams);

            EditTextUsesrMobNumberParams.setMargins(10,-5,0,0);
            EditTextUsesrMobNumber.setId(4);
            EditTextUsesrMobNumber.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            EditTextUsesrMobNumber.getBackground().setAlpha(0);
            EditTextUsesrMobNumber.setHint("Enter Mobile Number");
            EditTextUsesrMobNumber.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            EditTextUsesrMobNumber.setLayoutParams(EditTextUsesrMobNumberParams);

            registerForContextMenu(imageview);
            registerForContextMenu(EditTextUserName);
            registerForContextMenu(EditTextUsesrMobNumber);

            layout.addView(imageview);
            layout.addView(EditTextUserName);
            layout.addView(EditTextUsesrMobNumber);

            f.addView(layout);
        }


        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
              if(flag==0)
              {
                  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                  getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
              }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch(item.getItemId())
            {
                case R.id.contextmenuedit:  
                                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Edit item selected"+Integer.toString(imageview.getId()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            break;
                case R.id.contextmenudelete:    
                                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Delete item selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            break;
            }
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
}
```

With the help of ID I'm going to perform different operations on `ImageView` and `EditText`.

Comment: are your working with `onContextItemSelected(...)`?

Comment: Yes..wait I'm pasting my code..

Answer (score 1):

To dynamically set ID for a `View` use,

```
view.setId(int);
```

To get the ID use,

```
view.getId();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to get `ID` into your `onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)` like below:

```
  AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
  int index = info.position;
```

Comment: The way I'm setting ID to view is correct or not..or is there another way to do it...

Comment: @Aksh If you have only one `ImageView` then that is fine.

Comment: @Aksh where it is. i cant see any TextView

Comment: @Aksh then what you want do Actually?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48554/discussion-between-aksh-and-m-d)